# How do I automatically download an image on danbooru when the site loads with userscript?

Tags: tampermonkey, userscripts

I have little experience in coding so it's probably a problem with me doing stuff wrong but I couldn't find this anywhere either. For nearly 2 hours I tried to make a userscript that automatically downlaods the image of the danbooru post on site load so I don't have to click the download button (ikr really usefull) but I didn't get anywhere. I looked at so many different peoples codes that did similar things and read other stuff to try and make this work but I just could not do it.

This is what I came up with after looking at others similar code an reading some other stuff but nothing below did anything and I accepted my defeat momentarily, at this point I just want to make it work out of spite.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         aa
// @namespace    aa
// @version      0.1
// @description  aaaaaaaaaaa
// @author       aa
// @match        https://danbooru.donmai.us/posts/*
// @icon         none
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){
    'use strict';

document.querySelector('#post-option-download').click();

})();
```

also tried with `document.querySelector('#post-option-download').getAttribute('href').click();`

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         aaaaa
// @namespace    aa
// @version      0.1
// @description  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
// @author       aa
// @match        https://danbooru.donmai.us/posts/*
// @icon         none
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){
    'use strict';

document.querySelector('#post-option-download').click();

})();
```

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         aaaaaaaaaaaa
// @namespace    aaa
// @version      0.1
// @description  oh god help me
// @author       aa
// @match        https://danbooru.donmai.us/posts/*
// @icon         none
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

var button = document.querySelector('button[data-id="#post-option-download"]');

if (button) {
  button.click();
}
```

Comment: Get the `src` of the `img` element you want to download, then use [`GM_download()`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#api:GM_download). (remember to [`@grant`](https://www.tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#meta:grant) it first!)

Comment: Thank you! I don't know much so I had to go on a hunt how to use GM_download() and the right @grant to use but while searching I found a few thing I managed to piece together a code that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to piece together a script, that works, on the hunt for answers. Even tho I don't have much experience I got it eventually feel free to use any of this.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Danbooru Download and Favorite
// @namespace    AnimeRaupe
// @version      1.7
// @description  downloads and favorites the post you open automatically
// @author       AnimeRaupe
// @match        https://danbooru.donmai.us/posts/*
// @icon         none
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-end
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // favorites the Danbooru post
    document.querySelector("#add-to-favorites").click();

    // fet the element with id "post-option-download"
    var downloadLink = document.querySelector('#post-option-download a');

        var href = downloadLink.href;

        // hidden anchor element to trigger the download
        var hiddenAnchor = document.createElement('a');
        hiddenAnchor.style.display = 'none';
        hiddenAnchor.href = href;
        hiddenAnchor.download = downloadLink.getAttribute('download');
        document.body.appendChild(hiddenAnchor);

        // download
        hiddenAnchor.click();

        // clean up I think
        document.body.removeChild(hiddenAnchor);

})();
```